# Class constructor NodeEnvironment cannot be invoked without ‘new’

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, jestjs, babeljs

At first I encountered this error:

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/typeerror-class-constructor-nodeenvironment-cannot-be-invoked-without-new/151980

```
PS E:\MongoDB-University\MongoDB-JavaScript-Developer\mflix-js> npm test -t db-connection

> server@1.0.0 test
> jest --passWithNoTests "db-connection"

Determining test suites to run...Setup Mongo Connection
 FAIL  test/db-connection.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Class constructor NodeEnvironment cannot be invoked without 'new'



      at new MongoEnvironment (test/config/mongoEnvironment.js:30:113)
      at async TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at async runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
      at async _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at async runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.279 s
Ran all test suites matching /db-connection/i.
Teardown Mongo Connection
(node:17468) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:17468) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:17468) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:17468) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
PS E:\MongoDB-University\MongoDB-JavaScript-Developer\mflix-js>
```

And then I fixed it with this solution:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8973

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel",
      {
        "preset-env": { "targets": { "node": true } }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

But now, I have this error:

```
[user@top mflix-js]$ node -v
v14.17.1
[user@op mflix-js]$ npm test -t db-connection

> server@1.0.0 test
> jest --passWithNoTests "db-connection"

Determining test suites to run...Setup Mongo Connection
Test environment found at "/home/usr/Desktop/mflix-js/test/config/mongoEnvironment.js" does not export a "getVmContext" method, which is mandatory from Jest 27. This method is a replacement for "runScript".
```

Not sure where to go from here.

EDITED:

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -L ./index.js",
    "test": "jest --passWithNoTests",
    "test:watch": "jest --passWithNoTests --watch",
    "changestream:update": "node test/lessons/change-updates.js",
    "changestream:insert": "node test/lessons/change-insert.js"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "linters": {
      "*.js": [
        "prettier --write",
        "eslint --fix",
        "npm test",
        "git add"
      ]
    },
    "ignore": [
      "**/build/**",
      "**/data/**"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.47.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jest-runner": "^24.9.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mocha": "^9.2.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "npm-check-updates": "^3.1.21",
    "prettier": "^1.14.3",
    "sinon": "^5.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "husky": "^1.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-cli": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-express": "^1.6.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some context to get help. Result of `npm test` command heavily depend on nodejs application where packaje.json in located.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have added my `package.json`.

Comment: Sorry Free, the "application where package.json is located" means all files from the directory where the package.json is located, including subdirectories. `package.json` to some degree defines only files in `node_modules` subdirectory. You really need to narrow down your question. Did you write the app and tests yourself? If not, I'd suggest to ask the author, or the teacher if it is a lesson.